# How to check if user has granted the publish_actions permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I managed to request the publish_actions permission, but since it is revocable from the Apps tab on the Account Settings page I also must be able to check whether the permission is still granted. I tried it with the following approach:

```
// Check for publish_actions extended permission
var query = FB.Data.query('select publish_actions from permissions where uid={0}', fbuid);
query.wait(function(rows) {
    if(rows[0].publish_actions == 1) {
        console.log('The user has granted the extended permission');
    } else {
        console.log('The user has not granted the extended permission');
    }
});
```

This approach does work with the publish_stream permission for instance but not with the publish_actions permission. Would be very glad if someone could help, I'm totally frustrated.

**UPDATE**
type error. It works, sorry : ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated my own question so the answer is the code in the question.